# Why do I get a 'value of type [object] has no member 'lowercaseString'' error when iterating over a dictionary?

Tags: swift

I have several objects

```
Struct object {
   var title:String?
}

var one = object("green")
var two = object("black")
var three = object("blue")
```

Also I have a dictionary

```
var dict = ["a":[one, two], "b":[three]]
```

What I want is to iterate over dictionary values and find all objects that starts from "b".

I though about something like

```
for (key, value) in dict { 
  if value.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
}
```

but I get an error of

```
value of type [object] has no member 'lowercaseString'
```

how can I deal with this ?

Comment: The code you posted would not work, as it contains syntactical errors. please give us the code you struggle with.

Comment: value is Struct not a String here, so value.lowercaseString will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are iterating over a dictionary by looking at it keys and values.

But the values aren't strings but arrays of strings.

do

```
import Foundation

struct object {
    var title:String?
}

var one = object(title:"green")
var two = object(title:"black")
var three = object(title:"blue")

var dict = ["a":[one, two], "b":[three]]

for (key, value) in dict {
    for obj in value {
        if let title = obj.title {
            if title.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` is an array of object "[object]" but not a string, as defined by your code above:

```
var dict = ["a":[one, two], "b":[three]]
```

So you have to process the value as an array of `object`to find out what you want.

```
for (key, value) in dict {
    let found = value.filter({ (anObject: object) -> Bool in
        return anObject.title!.lowercaseString.containsString("b")
    })

    if (found.count > 0) {
        //you find what you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: no, I need to search inside each value. I need someway to get property title of each value element, to which I can apply lowercaseString